# Download file via AJAX request for error handling if file does not exist/or cannot be downloaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

I am trying to use ajax request to do a download for my file. This is my code:

```
const downloadFile = (element) => { 
    $.ajax({
        url: element.id,
        type: 'GET',  
        success: (result) => {
            window.location=element.id;
        },    
        error: (request,msg,error) => {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    })
} 

And HTML element: 
'<td>' + `<a id=hiddenAPIRoute href="#" onclick="downloadFile(this)">Download</a>` + '</td>' +
```

I am able to download but it does a double download. I like using ajax so I can have better error handling. I am aware of the download attribute of html 5 but I want to include an alert for users to view if the file is not accessible.

Comment: Its the same as window.location = *this/ismy/api/route${dynamicfile}* For the purposes of this post i am not including what the route actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fetch` and `URL.createObjectURL` for your workflow. And move your api url to `data-href`, using `id` is weird, it's for another purpose:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a data-href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" href="#"
        onclick="downloadFile(event)">Download</a>
    <script>

        const downloadFile = async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            try {
                const response = await fetch(e.target.dataset.href);
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error(await response.text());
                }
                const blob = await response.blob();
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = e.target.dataset.href;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                Promise.resolve().then(() => a.remove());
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }



    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In error handling you can do like this and show the error response however you like:-

```
    error: function(xhr, status, error1) {
         var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(err)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).